# Crashlytics is no longer showing error details

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Crashlytics used to show me the actual exception and line number of the crash. But now, it just says "Hmm, we could not fetch the latest session information."

I have not changed anything in my android code. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I am facing this problem right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. That was a bug due to a production issue that we had yesterday. It's all set now.

Comment: @Arda this could be happening for a variety of reasons such as if the crash occurred during the production issues. If you're able to reproduce this on new crashes, then please contact support(at)fabric(dot)io

Comment: Hi @mike , i cant not figure out. After 10-15 minutes, everything work fine =)

Comment: @MikeBonnell I am having the issue here too, showing `Hmm, we could not fetch session information.`

Comment: Working now, don't know what was the issue. Hope it doesn't appear again

Comment: Use the status page - http://status.fabric.io/ - to look for any cause of delays.